# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size <= 0 using ksoap2 library for consuming the WCF .SVC SOAP Web service

Tags: android, wcf, soap, android-asynctask, ksoap2

Thanks in advance please forgive me if I am making any mistake while explaining the problem.

I am new TO SOAP technology. I want to call a WCF .net based SOAP web service the request for the SOAP will look something like below

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <tem:IsServiceLive_V>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:version>1</tem:version>
  </tem:IsServiceLive_V>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

and I am trying to make the request in the code like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static String SOAP_ACTION1="http://tempuri.org/IService1/IsServiceLive_V";
    public static String SOAP_ACTION2="http://tempuri.org/IService1/IsServiceLive_V";
    public static String METHOD_NAME1="IsServiceLive_V";
    public static String METHOD_NAME2="IsServiceLive_V";
    public static String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
    public static String URL="http://64.27.48.117:3340/service/Service1.svc?wsdl";


     Button btnFar,btnCel,btnClear;

      EditText txtFar,txtCel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


      btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);

        btnCel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCel);

        btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);

        txtCel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCel);

        btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {

                  @Override

                  public void onClick(View v)

                  {

                        //Initialize soap request + add parameters

                      try
                      {
                          new SoapResult(1).execute();
                      }
                      catch(NullPointerException e)
                      {

                      }

                  }

            });
 }



public class SoapResult extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapObject>
{
    int flag_status;
    SoapObject final_result;

    public SoapResult(int flag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        flag_status=flag;
    }

    @Override
    protected SoapObject doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        if(flag_status==1)
        {
             //Initialize soap request + add parameters

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);       



            //Use this to add parameters

          /*  PropertyInfo property=new PropertyInfo();
            property.setName("tmp");
            property.setValue("GetRestaurantList");
          request.addProperty(property);*/

            request.addProperty("version", "1");


            //Declare the version of the SOAP request

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);



            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            System.out.println(request.toString());
            envelope.dotNet = true;



            try {

                  HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);



                  //this is the actual part that will call the webservice

                  androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

                  System.out.println("ok");

                  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

                  SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                  System.out.println(result.toString());
                  //SoapResult soap=(SoapResult)envelope.getResponse();



                  //Get the first property and change the label text
                final_result=result;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                  e.printStackTrace();
                  System.out.println("hiiii...");
            }




        return final_result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        if(flag_status==1)
            //txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());

        if(flag_status==0)
        {
            //              txtFar.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
        }



    }

}
```

and the SOAP response in SOAP format should look something like this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body>
    <IsServiceLive_VResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
       <IsServiceLive_VResult>true</IsServiceLive_VResult>
     </IsServiceLive_VResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

but it is giving me exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size <= 0

```
after the call     
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
```

The XML SOAP request and responses are generated using Soup UI tool and are working fine

just not getting where i am going wrong a little bit help would be appreciable..

Comment: can you check for / at end of your soap_action1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer for what i was looking for . for the WCF web services we have to create separate class for each method to get the data since it cannot be run from the code where you wanted the results . So if anyone has the problem that  I faced please do remember that to consume the WCF web service in your android project Create a different class for each method for the web service .I am giving an simple example below

```
public class GetNearBy {

public static String HOTEL_NAME="hotel_name";
public static String NUMBER_OF_BRANCHES="branches";
public static String IMAGE1="image1";
public static String IMAGE2="image2";
public static String IMAGE3="image3";
public static String IMAGE4="image4";
public static String IMAGE5="image5";
public static String IMAGE6="image6";
public static String HAS_EVENT="HasEvent";
public static String HAS_OFFER="HasOffer";
public static String HAS_MENU="HasMenu";
public static String HAS_POPULARFOOD="HasPopularFood";
public static String ID="Id";
public static String IS_OPEN="IsOpen";
public static String LAT="LAT";
public static String LONG="LONG";
public static String LOCATION="Location";
public static String STARS="Stars";
public static String FACILITY_COUNT="facility_count";
 private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetNearBy";
   private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetNearBy";
   private static final String URL = "http://xxxxxx/service/Service1.svc/soap";


   public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> connectToSOAPService()
  {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);



     // creating SOAP envelope
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

     // this should be true even in not .NET services
     envelope.dotNet = true;
     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

     HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

     String resultValue = "";
     try {
         // calling an action
         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

         // receiving response
         SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();



         for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++)
         {
            HashMap<String, String> result=new HashMap<String, String>();
            SoapObject ele1=(SoapObject)response.getProperty(i);


            String Hotel_name=ele1.getProperty("BranchName").toString();
            result.put(HOTEL_NAME, Hotel_name);

            data.add(result);
         }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {

     }





    return data;

}
```

}

and just call it from where you need to fetch the result from the WCF web service like this

```
GetNearBy.connectToSOAPService();
```

Answer (score 2):

Once I was having the same issue. There might be some problem with your service.

And use this

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
```

Instead of

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

Comment: not working with the change .. it is giving the exception that cannot serialize 1.   one is the input i am providing in the envelope

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
final String NAMESPACE = con.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.NAMESPACE);
            final String METHOD_NAME = "ItemsByCountry";
            final String SOAP_ACTION = con.getResources().getString(
                    R.string.SOAP_ACTION)
                    + METHOD_NAME;
            final String URL = con.getResources().getString(R.string.URL);

            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("userId", UserId);
            Request.addProperty("countryName", countryName);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelop;
            soapEnvelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelop.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelop.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE htp = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            htp.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelop);

            response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelop.getResponse();
```